# How to decide whether I should use AIR or Titanium

Tags: air, titanium

I may want to create a RIA but am wondering, whether [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) or [Titanium](http://titaniumapp.com/) is the way to go.

Do you think the open source version will last longer? Will it be better in anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although AIR  isn't open source yet, the technology stack it's on (Flex, Webkit, etc) is open source. Titanium definitely looks promising but has no where near the momentum and support AIR has yet. Until it's been actually released and has several production apps running on it I wouldn't bet too much on it.If you're looking to get involved in an open source project and actually work and help develop it that's something else...

---

Just to clarify, AIR lets you use HTML/js to build your apps as well.

Comment: Neither Flex nor Flash are open source.

Comment: Flex, Flash, Webkit - is open source.

Since when?

Comment: Except for Flash, Flex and WebKit are opensource http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK and http://webkit.org/

Comment: Is Flex opensource, or just the SDK?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone comes back to this post, I'll add my 2 cents.

Titanium has come along way in the last few months. It now has support for Ruby and Python. You can code your own modules in C++ (eg, IRC) and compile Titanium to have support for that module (Or you can code modules in Py/Ru/JS).

You can use flex, flash and silverlight all within Titanium. All have been tested and work without a hitch :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither, as both technologies are for creating desktop applications not RIAs.

Now if you were to ask how should you build your RIA... so that when, if, it comes to a point of you making a desktop version, which technology should you use, Flex or Javascript/HTML?

The answer becomes obvious once you decide between Flex or Javascript/HTML. If you do Flex then your desktop application will be in AIR; If you do Javascript/HTML your Descktop app will be in Titanium.

My suggestion, go with Flex - Air.  Both are environments where State is made easy.  Flex are written much like client (desktop) applications anyway as they have state.